# Custom page html headings plugin?

Tags: custom-header

Does anyone know of a plugin that lets you customize the heading area of each page or post with HTML? The heading area I refer to is directly above the main post content. An example is on http://www.woothemes.com/affiliates/

If you look in chrome developer tool or firebug, this div tag is their page-heading, below this is the main content area. For each page on their site it's unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple custom field and have it displayed on the page template.
Assuming you name the custom field "page-heading" this could help you:

```
<?php query_posts(); ?>
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page-heading', true)): ?>
    <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page-heading', true); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    Normal content
<?php endif; ?>
```

You should be easily able to add this to the page template or to a new template according to your need.